# Can FaceID be used as the sensor for MacOS Safari passkey?

Tags: passkey

Apparently passkey access can be controlled with biometric sensors.   Can?  How does one setup the iPhone / iPad's FaceID to control access to the passkeys?

Answer (score 1):

Try **Settings** > **Face ID & Passcode** > toggle **Password AutoFill** on.